# Use haproxy to redirect *.domain1.com/* to *.domain2.com/*

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, 301-redirect

I am struggling with some HAproxy rules for a while with no luck unfortunately.

Let's say I have domain1.com and domain2.com. I want to redirect everything from domain1.com to domain2.com, including subdomains and parameters.

Ex:

```
foo.domain1.com => foo.domain2.com
foo.domain1.com/?bar => foo.domain2.com/?bar
domain1.com/?bar => domain2.com/?bar
```

I've tried with `reqrep ^([^\ ]*\) (.*)domain1.com(.*) 1/ domain2.com\2` but it does not do the trick.

Comment: Redirecting after `req[i]rep` is tricky because the ACL rules are re-evaluated against the current buffer contents each time they are tested -- not against the initial buffer contents.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
acl is_domain1 hdr(host) -i *.domain1.com
redirect prefix http://domain2.com if is_domain1
```

That should take everything from domain1's request and redirect it to the right URI (including route and query options. I haven't tested it so you might need to [read about redirect](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#4-redirect) and tweak.